# Rating Control of AJAX Control Toolkit

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, rating

I want to use rating control of `AJAX Control Toolkit` and don' t need other controls in it. Loading the whole DLL take lots of time with slow connections. Is there any way to get DLL of rating control and editor control only?

Comment: the dll is loaded on the server, what has this to do with slow connections?

Comment: you mean the ajaxcontroltookit.dll with size about 3.5 mb has no effect in loading time of a page?

Comment: no it will not. it's the stuff that will be rendered in the aspx page.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a way of downloading the source files for the AJAX Control Toolkit which you could then strip and just use the Rating control.

Alternatively, you could use something like a jQuery plugin alternative:

http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/

Both only work when javascript is enabled, and I believe the AJAX Control Toolkit Rating control has a bug in which the page will skip to the top onclick.

Comment: i download the source. in its server folder i found 4 c# file for rating. how i can use this files?